# vscode advance search: exclude only files at the root of the folder

Tags: search, visual-studio-code

This is the relevant part of my folder structure:

```
data:
    ├── 1.py
    ├── 2.py
    ├── 3.py
    ├── a
    │   ├── 1.py
    │   ├──2.py
    │   ├── 3.py
```

I would like to exclude from the search the files `1.py,2.py,3.py` but only from the root folder, not from the `a` folder.

If I do this search :

```
include : C:\Users\user\Desktop\data\*  
exclude : 1.py,2.py,3.py
```

Then all the `1.py,2.py,3.py3` are excluded.

I tried `\1.py,\2.py,\3.py` and `.\1.py,.\2.py,.\3.py` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @user1383029, no unfortunately.